# Add Text Under Categories and Tags in Single Product Pages in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add some Global Text under Categories and Tags in Single Product Pages in Woo Commerce.

How Can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_product_meta_end` action hook like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'add_custom_text_below_product_categories', 10 );
function add_custom_text_below_product_categories() {
    echo '<p>Your custom text here...</p>';
}
```

This code snippet should be added to the functions.php of your child theme or via plugin like Code Snippets.

Comment: It worked, You are a rockstar mate! Thanks, big time!

Comment: No problem, glad this solved your issue. :)